# Submitting Data via GET with "Snoopy" in PHP

Tags: php, post, get, httprequest, snoopy

I'm trying to send data to a url via `GET` in PHP. I've decided to go with the [Snoopy Class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) after receiving an answer to another question here. The thing is, I cannot seem to find very good documentation/examples for the methods in this class.

I see the `->httprequest()` method, but I don't see where I can add an array of values along with the request.

Anybody a bit more familiar able to lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$vars = array( "fname" => "Jonathan", "lname" => "Sampson" );
$snoopy = new Snoopy();

$snoopy->httpmethod = "GET"; // is GET by default
$snoopy->submit( "http://www.example.com", $vars );
print $snoopy->results;
```

Comment: what if i have two form. form name=q and action=/search.